# Running method everytime I push the ViewController

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller

What *init* metod is called everytime a viewcontroller is pushed to window?

`-viewDidLoad` and `-initWithNibName` work only 1st time the view is started. But I want to do some startup checking in my vc everytime I start it.

Does such method exist? or do I have to declare it somehow manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try view controller's `viewWillAppear:` method (if you want to setup one specific controller).

Comment: God, so easy. Thanks a lot :)